# Oracle - Should processes limit be lower than sessions parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

```sql
SQL> select * from v$resource_limit;

RESOURCE_NAME   CURRENT_UTILIZATION MAX_UTILIZATION INITIAL_ALLOCATION LIMIT_VALUE
-------------   ------------------- --------------- ------------------ -----------
processes       88                  150             150                150
sessions        100                 174             248                248
```

Assuming that all the `sessions` are active and doesn't share `processes` with each other, is it okay to keep the `processes` limit significantly lower than `sessions` limit? In all the resources I've read, it's suggested / calculated to keep `sessions` as `processes * 1.5`. But what if the active `processes` reaches its limit and `sessions` could not able to assign a process to it?

We faced an exception intermittently while establishing a database connection on a successfully running application.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |  java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 | ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |  
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     at oracle.bc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalCoConnection.java:546)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 | Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 | ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |  
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:395)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/07/30 13:35:13 |     ... 54 more
```

Considering that the `MAX_UTILIZATION` of `processes` reached its limit of `150` at some point (and `sessions` reached upto `174`), I am suspecting that there isn't enough `processes` to assign it to a session which led me to think that `processes` should always be higher than or equal to `sessions` parameter.

```sql
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `sessions` can not be lower than `processes` by definition. Even if you try to set it, the database will just ignore it:

[SESSIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams234.htm#REFRN10197)

> Default value Derived: (1.5 * PROCESSES) + 22
>
> Oracle uses the default value of this parameter as its minimum. Values
> between 1 and the default do not trigger errors, but Oracle ignores
> them and uses the default instead.

You simply hit the process limit for that instance. Increase the limit accordingly, or investigate what application opened/opens these sessions.

Also the number of sessions for users should be limited by their profile, not the instance level `sessions` parameter.

[CREATE PROFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310) - look for `SESSIONS_PER_USER`.